# getting odd value when trying to replace NA when using R

Tags: r, na

Why am I getting "4" for agenew (row 23 of the 2nd display of the dataframe) after I execute the statement below?  It seems like I should be getting a "0" instead.

```
agenew[is.na(agenew)] <- 4 * sibsp + 3 * parch
```

This is the dataframe before executing the statement.

```
    age sibsp agenew parch
1  34.5     0     69     0
2  47.0     1     98     0
3  62.0     0    124     0
4  27.0     0     54     0
5  22.0     1     48     1
6  14.0     0     28     0
7  30.0     0     60     0
8  26.0     1     56     1
9  18.0     0     36     0
10 21.0     2     50     0
11   NA     0     NA     0
12 46.0     0     92     0
13 23.0     1     50     0
14 63.0     1    130     0
15 47.0     1     98     0
16 24.0     1     52     0
17 35.0     0     70     0
18 21.0     0     42     0
19 27.0     1     58     0
20 45.0     0     90     0
21 55.0     1    114     0
22  9.0     0     18     1
23   NA     0     NA     0
```

This is the dataframe after executing the statement

```
> newdf
    age sibsp agenew parch
1  34.5     0     69     0
2  47.0     1     98     0
3  62.0     0    124     0
4  27.0     0     54     0
5  22.0     1     48     1
6  14.0     0     28     0
7  30.0     0     60     0
8  26.0     1     56     1
9  18.0     0     36     0
10 21.0     2     50     0
11   NA     0      0     0
12 46.0     0     92     0
13 23.0     1     50     0
14 63.0     1    130     0
15 47.0     1     98     0
16 24.0     1     52     0
17 35.0     0     70     0
18 21.0     0     42     0
19 27.0     1     58     0
20 45.0     0     90     0
21 55.0     1    114     0
22  9.0     0     18     1
23   NA     0      4     0
```

Comment: try maybe `newdf$agenew[is.na(newdf$agenew)] <- 4 * newdf$sibsp + 3 * newdf$parch`

Answer (score 5):

Let `n` be the number of rows in your data.frame and `m` (where `m < n`) the number of rows where `agenew` is `NA`. Doing

```
agenew[is.na(agenew)] <- 4 * sibsp + 3 * parch
```

is wrong because the left-hand side has length `m` while the right-hand side has length `n`. That "4" you are getting as a replacement to `agenew` on row 23 (the second time agenew is `NA`) is the result of `4 * sibsp + 3 * parch` on the second row of your data.frame, not the 23rd...

What you meant to do is:

```
agenew[is.na(agenew)] <- (4 * sibsp + 3 * parch)[is.na(agenew)]
```

but there are more elegant ways to do this, for example:

```
agenew <- ifelse(is.na(agenew), 4 * sibsp + 3 * parch, agenew)
```

where here, all vectors have length `n`.

Note: As you did in your question, I am skipping the part where all of these statements should be evaluated within your data.frame (see `with`, `within`, `transform`, etc.), e.g.:

```
df <- transform(df, agenew = ifelse(is.na(agenew), 4 * sibsp + 3 * parch, agenew))
```

Comment: After looking at your suggestion the ifelse function seems like a better approach to me.  I will use it.

Comment: I am somewhat awkward when using R.  I was rerunning the data.frame function to evaluate newdf.  newdf <- data.frame(age,sibsp,agenew,parch).  Your suggestion seems better and I will try to remember it in the future.  Thanks,  Warren